# Releasing I/O resource properly

Tags: java, file, io

I was wondering that what is the best/appropriate way to release file resources/handles.

Traditional code,

```
BufferredInputStream stream = null
try{
  ----
  stream = new BufferredInputStream(new FileInputStream());
  ----
} finally{
  if(stream != null){
    stream.close()
  }
```

}

Will the file handle be released by closing `BufferredInputStream.close` alone or it needs the underlying `stream(i.e. FileInputStream.close())` also to be called explicitly.

`P.S. Javadoc for [FilterOutputStream.close]` method specifies that it will explicitly close the underlying stream too. But other streams doesn't seem to have this in the doc.

```
[FilterOutputStream.close]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close%28%29
```

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can easily test it by closing only the BufferredInputStream object and than trying to manipulate the FileInputStream and see if any exception of closed stream is raised. I believe it will be closed as you see in many doc examples the underlying stream is created anonymously

Comment: Just a suggestion : If you are using JDK 7, use the try-with-resources, its a lot simpler. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion JavaNewbie_M107. Java 7 is not added into the project yet. Am looking forward to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always check the source code for the underlying class to determine the exact behavior.

However, in this case calling `close()` on `BufferedInputStream` will also close the underlying stream i.e. `FileInputStream`.

The source code is available [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java#BufferedInputStream.close%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

When multiple streams are chained closing the stream that was last to be constructed will close the underlying stream. So, closing `BufferedInputStream` will also close the underlying `FileInputStream`.

So you just call close() on one stream and it will automatically close the underlying stream.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The javadoc doesn't mention so. Is there any reference or proof to support this answer. Am working on a critical problem to stop file handle leaks.

Comment: Check the link in Mr.Usman's answer. Scroll to the bottom and you will see how the close() method works. It is closing the InputStream that was chained to BufferdInputStream.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. When in doubt, always check the source code. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java.html the close method is closing "in" which was chained to BufferedInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

BufferredInputStream doesn't itself hold any system resources so BufferredInputStream.close() will simple propagate the close call to InputStream it wraps.. so it should do just fine.